# MySQL Group data of three columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, calc

Good day, dear colleagues!

Please, could somebody tell me how to make a group from 3 columns? For example, there are three columns of the same type A, B, C in one table, which store the same type of data, such as: "bread", "water", "chocolate". And also we have date column.

It's look like:

```
Col_A     | Col_B     | Col_C   | Date       
--------- | --------- | ------- | ---------- 
Bread     | Null      | Water   | 19.01.2016 
Bread     | Bread     | Water   | 22.02.2016 
Chocolate | Chocolate | Null    | 18.03.2016
```

And I want to calculate how many products sold grouped by month?
Expecting result:

```
January -> Bread 1, Water 1
February ->Bread 2, Water 1
March -> Chocolate 2
```

For one column I used query like:

```
SELECT A, COUNT(A) FROM MyDB GROUP BY month(Date)
```

But I don't know how to calculate for 3 column at time?
Thanks for any helps in advance!

Comment: do you want all of these column result in a single row or multiple row??

Comment: *which store the same type of data* this is symptomatic of poor design

Comment: First of all thank you a lot for interest. 1. I want to calculate it in one column. Calculate how many uniq items were in each month of the year. 2. No, it's not a poor design. That data from different sources and may be one or two or all four at the one day.

Comment: The question is closed. Thanks to all. Decision is right down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to put them all in one column of course :)

```
SELECT my_column, COUNT(my_column) FROM (
    SELECT Col_A AS my_column FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Col_B FROM your_table
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Col_C FROM your_table
) sq
GROUP BY my_column;
```

Also you should consider to redesign your database. As you see this table is suboptimal.

Comment: What is the problem? Are you using MySQL 5.7? With 5.7. parantheses are needed around each SELECT statement in the subquery (the unioned ones).

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. I'm using MySQL 5.5.54. And used query that's working now, but it's ok only for 1 column. **`SELECT Event_1, COUNT(Event_1), Date_of_flight FROM flightdata where (date_format(str_to_date(Date_of_flight, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') >= '2016-01-01' and date_format(str_to_date(Date_of_flight, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d') < '2018-01-01') GROUP BY month(Date_of_flight) ORDER BY date_format(str_to_date(Date_of_flight, '%d.%m.%Y'), '%Y-%m-%d');`** and such Event_1, I have 4: Event_1, Event_2, Event_3 and Event_4.

Comment: What do you mean with "it's ok only for 1 column"? I think I can help you better, if you provide some sample data (you can use http://sqlfiddle.com) and the query you tried.

Comment: I understood your problem. You have to use `UNION (ALL)` to put them all in one column! Have you tried that? Is there an error message of some sort? Another problem with your query is the following: There's a rule, that every column from your `select` clause that's not in your `group by` clause must have an aggregate function applied to it. That's because the rows for each group get "collapsed" and a random row for a group is displayed, when you don't use an aggregate function.

Comment: Thank you Fancy Pants! I made it with your help! It's working!! Thank you!! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Use `UNION ALL` to get the value as a column and use a combination of `GROUP_CONCAT` and `CONCAT`.

**Query**

```
select z.`Month`, group_concat(concat(z.`Col`, ' ', z.`Count`) separator ', ') `Col` from(
  select t.`Date`, monthname(t.`Date`) as `Month`, t.`Col`, count(t.`Col`) as `Count` from(
    select `Col_A` as `Col`, `Date` from `your_table_name`
    union all
    select `Col_B`, `Date` from `your_table_name`
    union all
    select `Col_C`, `Date` from `your_table_name`
  )t
  group by monthname(t.`Date`), t.`Col`
)z
group by z.`Month`
order by month(z.`Date`);
```

**[`SQL Fiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ce14d3/1)**

Comment: Thank you! I will experiment with it, and feedback you.